# Is there a folder for local unix sockets under Android?

Tags: file-system

On a normal linux installation the right path for local sockets is /run as described in the FSH.

But this folder does not exist under Android. I have checked both an old and a new device.

There is the folder /dev/socket but it may only be used by the init process (as described [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/net/LocalSocketAddress.java)).

So I wonder what the right path is?

Comment: There's no concept of shared directories like `/run`, `/tmp` and `/var` on Android. Neither the IPC through UNIX sockets (with path) and named pipes etc. is the recommended way. Instead use Binder IPC.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Binder IPC is for system-level developement. I want to do IPC on app level (my process is running as root)...